# Filter rows that contain exact strings in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to filter rows from `df` that contain `air` as a stand-alone word in a column

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(13, 34, 5, 124, 56),
                 y = c('air transport', 'hairdressing', 'airport', 'repair', 'frontend'))
```

This gives me rows that partially contain `air`

```
df %>% filter(grepl('air',y))

    x             y
1  13 air transport
2  34  hairdressing
3   5       airport
4 124        repair
```

Here is my intended result

```
   x             y
1 13 air transport
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\\b` to match a zero-length word boundary:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(grepl('\\bair\\b', y))
```